# Tomcat 8.0 giving 404 for Jersey rest service

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, jersey

I am new to Java, I have been trying to create a rest service using Jersey 2.23 on Tomcat 8.0
I have read many other posts for the same, changed it accordingly and I am still getting the same error.

[image]

URL: http://localhost:8080/RestCalculator/api/GetStarted

here is my service

```
package com.restcalculator;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.InputStream;

@Path("/")
public class RestfulCalculator 
{
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    @Path("/GetStarted")
    public Response GetStarted()
    {
        String output = "RestfulCalculator Service is Running. Ping @" + new Date().toString();
        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
    }

}
```

my POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>RestCalculator</groupId>
  <artifactId>RestCalculator</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-all</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

and my web.xml

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>RestCalculator</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Rest Calculator Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.restcalculator</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Rest Calculator</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

I have updated the servlet class name as per Jersey 2.23. Please tell me what m I doing wrong.

**EDIT 2:**

Fixed servlet name, Tomcat server is running and index.html is loading.
I am getting this error now. It seems more relevant, bt I am not able to understand the problem.

```
    Sep 09, 2016 5:01:08 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Sep 09, 2016 5:01:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet Jersey Rest Calculator Service as unavailable
Sep 09, 2016 5:01:08 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet [Jersey Rest Calculator Service] in web application [/RestCalculator] threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:518)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1091)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1027)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5038)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5348)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1407)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1397)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is my first project and I haven't been able to run a single thing. Please help.

Comment: try to use `http://localhost:8080/RestCalculator-0.0.1/api/GetStarted`

Comment: tried.. m getting the same error, nor is my index.html is loaded

Comment: You use a standalone tomcat?

Comment: Using eclipse server, installed tomcat separately

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in the log. Mybe the applicationn is not started

Answer (score 0):

The URL should be

> URL: http://localhost:8080/GetStarted

, if you want to reach the GetStarted() method.

Other than that, you would have to tweak the code as below:

```
package com.restcalculator;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.InputStream;

@Path("/RestCalculator/api")
public class RestfulCalculator 
{
    ...

}
```

So that you can use the same url:

URL:

> http://localhost:8080/RestCalculator/api/GetStarted

Answer (score 0):

The path should be http://localhost:8080/**app_name**/api/GetStarted. **app_name** is your projectname in Eclipse. Check **.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0|tmp1\wtpwebapps** directory under your workspace to see if your application is realy deployed after starting server(assuming you are using wtp). If it's not there then you have an error or you didn't add your application to the server. If it's there check the name.

Comment: I checked.. .metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\RestCalculator  has my index.html n WEb-inf n meta-inf folders... could it be tomcat issue? any idea y m I not able to get index.html on localhost:8080

Comment: You are getting errors because In your web.xml `<servlet-name>` of the `<servlet-mapping>` must be exactly the same as the `<servlet-name>` of `<servlet>`

Comment: I tried that, localhost:8080/RestCalculator now loads my index.html.. bt localhost:8080/RestCalculator/api/GetStarted is still 404. I have added the new error in the question. Can you understand the problem?

Comment: Seems that your dependency is to **Jersey 1.X** while your configuration is **Jersey 2.X** . Check this tutorial for both **maven** and **web.xml** configurations: (http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html)